# Unable to Install Ubuntu 14 next to Windows 7 (same HDD)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Desktop PC.

I made a bootable USB-Stick and booted from it. I came into the mask which gave me the options "Try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, ..".

I chose Install Ubuntu and then my Computer hung up on a screen which says:

```
ACPI PCC probe failed.

sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] No caching mode page found..

(more lines with even more cryptic info)

failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
```

I'm stuck there. I can't go any further. Only option is to shut down computer manually... (same problem for 'Try Ubuntu' as well.)
I try to enter the compatible mode, even add nomodeset before quiet, etc, but the screen won't move further.

Thanks for any help.

Motherboard: ASROCK H61M Core: i3-2100

Comment: It may be due to the fact that you are trying to install a 64-bit operating system on the machine which does not support 64-bit OSes. Try installing a 32-bit OS

Comment: 64 bit OS are named as amd64 while 32 bit are named i386.

Comment: The reason of the problem is that I plugged the SATA in a secondary slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the problem is that I plugged the SATA in a secondary slot.